# Help to understand the grammar for the sentence

Tags: grammar

[image]
I can understand the meaning of the sentence, but I have some doubt on the grammar point.

First, I think NCSC is the singular form, so it should be **NCSC assesses**.

Second, I don't understand the grammar of the last part of the sentence **... within the context of the existing UK telecommunications infrastructure cannot be mitigated.** As I know, *of* should not be followed by a *that clause*.

Can someone help me with this? Thanks!

Comment: And NCSC is ???

Comment: Are you sure NCSC access is not a compound noun? Otherwise, it means NCSC is a group of something and author wants to say each part has the access. However, I am not sure what does Access mean here!! something like NCSC access that ... arising from, the use of ..., cannot be mitigated.

Comment: @user3169 NCSC should be *National Computer Security Center* or *National Cyber Security Center*.

Comment: As I understand so far, the main clause within that clause is "the national security risks cannot be mitigated". *Arising from ......infrastructure* modifies *risks*. I am still unsure if it should be NCSC assess or NCSC assesses?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Overall this sentence is convoluted, but still grammatical.

The British treat certain collective nouns as plural, that  Americans are more comfortable treating as singular ([more about this](https://blog.oxforddictionaries.com/2011/09/05/agreement-over-collective-nouns/)).  For example:

> The Rural Affairs and Environment Committee **were** provided with ...

The basic structure of the sentence is:

> NCSC assess that the national security risks [of some kind] cannot be mitigated

This *of some kind* is those risks:

> arising from the use of [X] within [context Y]

I'm not sure what you mean by "*of* should not be followed by a *that* clause", since I don't see any such clause.